# Xfire can't take screenshots

Tags: xfire

I got all the settings right. I located the file it should save, but it is empty even though I am hitting the right key. What might be the problem? (Playing eve online and it is being tracked)

Answer (score 1):

Xfire ingame has to be enabled as well. When you successfully take a picture you will hear a camera shutter sound, and then once you exit the game a new window will popup with all the screenshots/video you took to let you choose what to do with them.